# Shadow Hand as a Warblade?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, class-feature

I do believe that there should be some Alternate Class Feature that'll allow warblade to take non-warblade discipline. Well, you know, in Dragon Magazine, but it's not really easy to dig it up... Where can I find those ACFs?

Answer (score 6):

[Here's the giant list](http://brilliantgameologists.com/boards/index.php?topic=7908) of alternate class features for all 3.5 classes. There exist no ACFs for the Book of Nine Swords classes.

**The canonical solution to this problem is just to multiclass.**

There exist many compelling multiclass builds and your intentions are the problem that multiclassing is intended to solve.

However, for your specific requirements, two feats exist within the book to provide for the "dabbling" that you want: *Martial Study*, and *Martial Stance*.

While this does not allow unlimited selection from the discipline (that's what multiclassing at the appropriate level is for) it certainly allows for cherry-picking delicious delicious maneuvers. Given that you can keep taking the bloody feats, I believe this satisfies your requirements.

Comment: Martial Study is limited to three times total.

Comment: Also, although it's not specifically asked, it might be worth pointing out that maneuvers gained via Martial Study *do* use the recovery mechanic of whatever initiator class you wish, which might be a compelling reason to use them instead of multiclassing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the same as was published in Dragon (heck, I can't find anything in my dragon indices), BUT I did find the [Soldier of Shadow](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Soldier_of_Shadow_%283.5e_Alternate_Class_Feature%29) on the D&D wiki

Hope that helps.

Comment: I've found that one too, but the only resources allowed on the DnD forum I play are official ones (and this one is most likely homebrew one)